# MySql persistent layer not working

Tags: mysql, orbeon

I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 10.10
- Mysql 5.1.49
- Tomcat 6.0.28
- Mysql/J 5.1.15
- Orbeon 3.9.0.rc1.201103220245 CE

I have been trying to get the Mysql persistence layer working for 8+ hours to no avail. I keep getting the same error in the logs below and forms are not saved or published. I have also included the paths and config files. Mysql shows 3 successful DB connections with the orbeon user when tomcat starts so I think the userid/pasword is good. I have tried adding resource tags in web.xml with no luck. greatly appreciate help on getting this working. I have tried orbeon 3.8.0 CE and the latest nightly build with the same results.

```
orbeon.log
2011-03-23 19:13:48,321 INFO  OrbeonServletContextListener  - Servlet Context Listener - Context initialized.
2011-03-23 19:14:00,054 INFO  ProcessorService  - Servlet - Servlet initialized.
2011-03-23 19:14:00,064 INFO  ProcessorService  - / - Received request
2011-03-23 19:14:00,682 INFO  ProcessorService  - / - Timing: 623 - Cache hits for cache.main: 43, fault: 37, adds: 37, expirations: 0, success rate: 53%
2011-03-23 19:14:00,684 INFO  ProcessorService  - /home/ - Received request
2011-03-23 19:14:01,466 INFO  ProcessorService  - /home/ - Timing: 782 - Cache hits for cache.main: 402, fault: 83, adds: 84, expirations: 0, success rate: 82%
2011-03-23 19:14:11,724 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/orbeon/builder/summary - Received request
2011-03-23 19:14:14,095 WARN  Version  - Feature is not enabled in this version of the product: cached XForms instance
2011-03-23 19:14:14,264 WARN  Version  - Feature is not enabled in this version of the product: xpath-analysis
2011-03-23 19:14:16,236 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/i18n/fr-resources/orbeon/builder - Received request
2011-03-23 19:14:16,704 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/i18n/fr-resources/orbeon/builder - Timing: 468 - Cache hits for cache.main: 353, fault: 64, adds: 64, expirations: 0, success rate: 84%
2011-03-23 19:14:16,777 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/resource/crud/orbeon/builder/form/form.xhtml - Received request
2011-03-23 19:14:17,248 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/resource/crud/orbeon/builder/form/form.xhtml - Timing: 471 - Cache hits for cache.main: 324, fault: 60, adds: 59, expirations: 0, success rate: 84%
2011-03-23 19:14:17,800 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/service/mysql/search/orbeon/builder - Received request
2011-03-23 19:14:18,506 ERROR SQLProcessor  - PreparedStatement:
null
2011-03-23 19:14:18,508 ERROR ProcessorService  - Exception at oxf:/apps/fr/persistence/mysql/search.xpl (executing XSLT transformation)
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.DatabaseContext.getConnection(DatabaseContext.java:56)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessorInterpreterContext.getConnection(SQLProcessorInterpreterContext.java:334)
```

---

```
/etc/tomcat6/server.xml;
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <!--
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  -->
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
    <!-- Orbeon MySQL persistence layer -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              poolPreparedStatements="true"
              username="orbeon"
              password="xxxxxxx"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orbeon"/>

  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    -->


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
           the request and response data received and sent by Tomcat.
           Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
      <!--
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
      -->

      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
           available for use by the Realm.  -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
        -->

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>


/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config/properties-local.xml
<!--
    This file is an empty template for your own properties-local.xml file. Please follow the instructions here:

    http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties
-->
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

    <!-- This is an example of property which overrides an existing property's default value:
    <property as="xs:NMTOKENS"
              name="oxf.xforms.logging.debug"
              value="document model submission submission-details control event action analysis server html"/>
    -->
    <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.app.uri.*.*.*"
                             value="/fr/service/mysql"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.mysql.datasource"
                             value="mysql"/>
</properties>
```

---

NEW /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config/properties-local.xml

```
http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties
```

-->

```
<!-- This is an example of property which overrides an existing property's default value:
<property as="xs:NMTOKENS"
          name="oxf.xforms.logging.debug"
          value="document model submission submission-details control event action analysis server html"/>
-->
   <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.akcforms.*.*" value="mysql"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.datasource" value="mysql"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the properties you are using to configure the persistence layer are correct as they recently changed. You are using very recent post 3.9 nightly build which already has the new system. This system will come with Orbeon Forms 3.10 or 4.0, whatever it ends up being called. You can read more about the difference in the [MySQL and Oracle documentation](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers) and check that you are using the appropriate properties for the version you are using.

Comment: I have configured my setup per the instructions listed above for Orbeon 3.10. New forms ar still using the eXist database instead of the Mysql database. What else can i check? I am updating the above question with my new propeties-local.xml and logs that show no JDBC activity from Orbeon. Thanks.

Comment: I am puzzled. The property that matters here is `oxf.fr.persistence.provider.akcforms.*.*`. If you set this to `mysql`, then the MySQL provider should be used. If there was a configuration with the datasource, you would get an error instead (eXist wouldn't be used). So it is as if that property wasn't read correctly. Instead of `oxf.fr.persistence.provider.akcforms.*.*`, could you try using `oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*` (that is: telling Orbeon Forms you want to use MySQL for all your forms)?

Comment: Hi @avernet I have similar issue while configuring it with Tomcat 7.0.22, I supplied the context file but still it says Name jdbc not found in this context\

Comment: @JigarJoshi In some cases, I have seen people have this problem when they define the `<Resource>` in their `server.xml` outside of the `<Context>`. Is your defined inside `<Context>`, as I would suggest it should be?